# Bootstrap Docs Fixed Navigation Menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm sure this is a dumb question, but on the [docs page](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) when I click an option on the left, the active class is added to the list element. I'm not seeing the code where this actually happens though. I'm trying to debug an issue in my code with fixed nav that doesn't happen on the bootstrap docs. Can someone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: Here is my actual issue - when I click the fixed navigation on the left side, the menu flickers pretty badly. You can see it on my example page here: http://shanetest.site44.com/test.html#intro

Comment: Could you please post a bit of your code? Also, I would imagine the bootstrap docs site has some jquery that basically binds an event listener to anchor tag and when that even fires, jQuery adds the active class and show the sub-elements in the side nav. I'm happy to show you some example code if you give me a bit more context.

Comment: Right - but I wasn't able to find that code that binds an event listener, which led me to think they were doing it differently that I am. Maybe I'll put together a jsfiddle that demonstrates my actual issue.

Comment: Did you import jquery.js and bootstrap.js?

Comment: I updated my question with an example page demonstrating the issue.

Comment: I haven't seen anything like that before. An observation: When I click on a link, the nav bar goes blank until I move my mouse away. I would image there is some conflict between the css :hover attribute and the .click call back. Btw is mathvine opensource/are you looking for help? It looks like a really cool project.

Comment: Hmm - I'm not sure if I'm seeing that, unless I'm misunderstanding. It is not open source, but I'm definitely going to be looking for help. Interested?

Comment: I'm very interested! I love math and I've been working with a few teachers to try to make learning more interactive through simulation and more efficient through online communication. Shoot me an email laxnski [at] gmail [dot] com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a webkit bug.

Try to add the following css property into your affix class

```
.affix {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
}
```